# How to write unit test case for the static class and methods

Tags: unit-testing

I have below static class and method written to get the Sitecore Item by its path.

```
public static class MyService
    {
        public static Item GetItemByShortPath(SiteContext siteContext, string shortPath)
        {
             var fullPath = siteContext.StartPath + "/"+ shortPath;
            return siteContext.Database.GetItem(fullPath);
        }
}
```

Can someone please help me in writing unit test case for this code?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of the below skeleton test.

```
    [TestClass]
    public class MyServiceTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void GetItemByShortPath_Should_Return_Item()
        {
            // Arrange
            var database = new Db
            {
                new Database.GetItem("Home") { { "Title", "Welcome" } }
            };
    
            var siteContext = new SiteContext
            {
                StartPath = "/sitecore/content/Home",
                Database = database.Database
            };
    
            var shortPath = "Title";
    
            // Act
            var result = MyService.GetItemByShortPath(siteContext, shortPath);
    
            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
            Assert.AreEqual("Welcome", result["Title"]);
        }
    
        [TestMethod]
        public void GetItemByShortPath_Should_Return_Null_When_Item_Not_Found()
        {
            // Arrange
            var database = new Db();
    
            var siteContext = new SiteContext
            {
                StartPath = "/sitecore/content/Home",
                Database = database.Database
            };
    
            var shortPath = "NonExistentItem";
    
            // Act
            var result = MyService.GetItemByShortPath(siteContext, shortPath);
    
            // Assert
            Assert.IsNull(result);
      

  }
}
```

In these test cases:

1. `GetItemByShortPath_Should_Return_Item`: This test checks whether the `GetItemByShortPath` method returns a valid item when given a valid short path.
2. `GetItemByShortPath_Should_Return_Null_When_Item_Not_Found`: This test checks whether the `GetItemByShortPath` method returns `null` when the item with the specified short path does not exist in the database.

***Note:***

***1. Make sure to change the code according to your solution.***

***2. Make sure to adjust the test data and assertions as per your
specific requirements and actual implementation.***

***Hope this might help.***

Comment: If this works for you please mark it as answered @alok-kumar

Comment: also check https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2879/how-to-get-started-with-sitecore-unit-testing-with-sitecorefakedb?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I'd say FakeDb is outdated and I'd not recommend using it nowadays. Sitecore 9 brought abstractions so regular mocks can be utilized.

AutoFixture and [Sitecore Customizations for AutoFixture](https://github.com/sshushliapin/AutoSitecoreCustomizations/blob/master/AutoSitecoreCustomizations.Tests/Scenarios.cs) help to reduce the amount of code needed to get started. See how the success scenario could look like:

```
[Theory, AutoNSubstituteData]
public void GetItemByShortPathReturnsExpectedIfFound(
    Database database, Item expected)
{
    var siteContext = new SiteContext(new SiteInfo(new StringDictionary
    {
        { "rootPath", "/sitecore/content/mysite" },
        { "startItem", "home" }
    }))
    {
        Database = database
    };
    database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/mysite/home/page1").Returns(expected);
    var actual = MyService.GetItemByShortPath(siteContext, "page1");
    Assert.Same(expected, actual);
}
```

Of course, there shold be more test to cover all the possible scenarions, e.g. what if database is null, what if `/short-path` (with extra slash) is passed instead of `short-path` etc. But, general idea should be clear.

In order to make it working, just copy few classes from [here](https://github.com/sshushliapin/AutoSitecoreCustomizations/blob/master/AutoSitecoreCustomizations/AutoNSubstituteDataAttribute.cs) into your solution. The entire repo can be used as a reference.